# Unsupported content type 'application/octet-stream' when decoding file part

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipart

I have Spring Web service consuming Multipart:

```
@PostMapping(path = "uploadFile", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> uploadFile(                                                       @RequestPart("file")FilePart filePart
```

and a Spring RestTemplate client producing that Multipart:

```
var builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
builder.part("file", new ByteArrayResource(data){
  @Override
  public String getFilename()
  {
    return attachmentKey;
  }
});
builder.part("filename", attachmentKey);
var body = builder.build();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
return Mono.just(restTemplate.postForEntity("/uploadFile", requestEntity, Boolean.class).getBody());
```

I'm keeping getting error on server:

> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:
> Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported]

I was double, triple and quadruple checking every line of code, comparing it with internet resources, and trying all posssibilities I've found, and I couldn't find an error, only after setting breakpoint in the constructor of the exception I've found out, that the actual problem is the encoding of the file part and not the http request itself:

[image]

Apparently the RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver doesn't accept application/octet-stream as a valid encoding for a file part (but what else should be set there?)

I'm very confused, I'm migrating from other stack (Jetty + HttpClient) where I've never approached such errors.

Is this a problem with encoding of the multipart message? Or I need to make Spring process binary resources in the multipart? How?